# Can't get Entity Framework zero-or-one to zero-or-one relations to work

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am fairly new to Entity Framework and I've spend the last <strike>4 hours</strike> day trying to make a (to me seemingly) simple relation to work.

I have three classes: Person, House, Garage

- A Person can have none or multiple (0..n) Houses and Garages
- A House can have (0..1) a Garage and must only belong to one Person
- A Garage can therefore also have (0..1) a House and must only belong to one Person
- There are Garages with no Houses and Houses with no Garages
- At no point can there be a Garage or House without a related Person (that's easy, I think I got that one)

By now I've read like 10 different documentations that all make matters only more confusing to me. I've tried solving it using annotations but it seems that I also have to incorporate this fluent api stuff.

The furthest I've gotten is to have Houses and Garages associated to a Person, but not to eachother. Now I've been stuck having to define the principle end of a relationship, which I don't even understand what it's supposed to do.

Right now I get

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.

from trying to solve a barrage of different errors.

I've been implementing relations like these for ages in PHP, manually, by writing all my own queries. This is the first time I'm doing database stuff in a bigger framework that is supposed to make things easier, but so far I'd have had more success in filling the objects myself from a DatabaseReader.

From my logical point of view the relation between the three Classes/Tables should be really simple yet I can't find examples of similar relations or get it to just work.

So my questions are:

- Is a zero-or-one to zero-or-one relation really that special that it's so hard to design in code first?
- Wouldn't the Garage table not need a foreign key to the House table, because it's possible to find the corresponding House by filtering the House table for the GarageId? I've tried implementing a lookup of the House in code but noticed that it breaks a lot of LINQ because it's not a database property anymore.
- I've tried Annotations and Fluent API, all the top examples of 0..1 to 0..1 (or really, any other) relations from SO, tried swapping fields in the modelBuilder because it didn't look right in the DB... until reaching a point where the DB looks kinda okay but the code still refuses to work. What else can I try?
- Maybe I've been doing all the DB stuff wrong all my life and having relations like these are unhealthy for everyone involved. In that case, what alternatives would you suggest that I try to replicate the Person-House-Garage relation described above? Are there any helper classes that I can shove between Houses and Garages to get it to work?

I have prepared a demo project: https://github.com/Zaphox/DatabaseTest
It contains the three classes, context and a test of the relations that should successfully complete (but doesn't).

Thanks for any and all help and hints that lead to the solution to this problem!

Z.

## Update 1

After trying all suggestions I noticed that any circular relation causes errors in EF and it seems that it's just not possible to create references like these, even 0..1 to 0..1 self references do not seem to work.

I have however implemented a hack that at least lets me work, but it's horrible and I would love for someone to tell me that there's a better way.

1. Only Houses have references to Garages, not vice versa
2. To get a House belonging to a Garage a separate query is required (`db.Buildings.OfType<House>().Where(h => h.Garage.Id == myGarage.Id).First()`)

Also I thought about adding a NotMapped House field in the Garage which does a lookup for the house by itself but it interferes with other queries, so that's not a valid option either.

What annoys me most is that there are a lot of articles about self-references and the likes, but only for 1 to n relations. Any attempt to make a 1 to 1, or 0..1 to 0..1 relation, always fails with EF not being able to figure out the "order".

The thing is that EF thinks it has to make put a GarageId FK in the House table, and a HouseId FK in the Garage table, which is nonsense. I only need a GarageId in the House table, which can used as a backwards reference. I can implement this code-wise but it's not compatible to EF queries and usually interferes with other running queries because you can't run two queries at once.

The demo project on GitHub is updated with the current version, which kinda works but requires a lot of additional querying every time I want to find the House belonging to a Garage.

Comment: Will the `House` or `Garage` classes have attributes other than links to a person and / or another `House` / `Garage`?

Comment: Yes, all these classes are empty for now so I can figure out the relations, but later they will be full of attributes (name, address, size), probably also links (cleaning company and other contacts, links to HVAC documents, ...).

Comment: Apparently the problem is `Garage` and `House` relationship - both being optional and none of them being principal/dependent. I think EF does not support such association, as a workaround I could suggest using many-to-many relationship (I know it's not exactly what you need, but it's the only one which can handle house w/o garage and garage w/o house).

Comment: So I could limit the many-to-many relationships in code to only have one of each, `House` and `Garage`. I think that shouldn't be a problem but if there's any way to properly define the relationship I'd prefer it over having n-to-m tables and keeping them sane manually.

Comment: @ZaphodFox Indeed :)

Comment: Added Update 1, found a half-working solution / hack which at least lets me use the db structure while having to manually associate Houses to Garages. Not marking this topic as solved as it's not a proper solution and I'm still looking for a way to have a `House` property on `Garage` and a `Garage` property on `House` without having circular relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the problem is the relationship between `House` and `Garage`.

> I only need a GarageId in the House table, which can used as a backwards reference.

In fact this is what happens by default when you put **only** `Garage` navigation property on `House` class (with the only difference that the FK column name is `Garage_Id`). This is called unidirectional association. With such setup EF considers `House` to be the dependent, `Garage` to be the principal and both to be optional. The important part is that FK column is created in **dependent** table.

So this is what you have currently in your test project and it works. The problem arises when you make the association bidirectional by adding `House` property to `Garage` class:

```
public class House
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Garage Garage { get; set; }
    public string Style { get; set; }
}

public class Garage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public House House { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

In this case EF has no enough information what is your intention, so you need to provide that information. Remember that you want `GarageId` FK in `House` table, so here is the corresponding Fluent configuration that you need to add (the `Map` part is optional - if you skip it, the FK column will be called `Garage_Id` as in your current project):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<House>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.Garage)
    .WithOptionalDependent(e => e.House)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("GarageId"));
```

and everything will work as expected.

Comment: It does indeed. I've found an tried a lot of very similar code which always resulted in errors for me, I suppose I must have made a mistake somewhere. Your example works perfectly well, thanks!

Comment: You are not the only one who makes a mistakes :) The problem is that EF does some default assumptions which sometimes lead to weird behaviors. For instance, before adding the `House` nav property, I used exactly the same fluent config, with the only difference `.WithOptionalDependent()` (note the lack of argument) and it worked. Then I added the nav property, but forget to update the config, and it stopped working. After looking at database, I've noticed it silently added `House_Id` FK to `Garage` table! Correcting the config fixed the issue.

Comment: So one should be very careful with these relations and always check the generated tables. Cheers.

Comment: Will have to buy a book about EF since I'm having trouble understanding the docs. If I remember correctly, all code I tried also had no arguments in `.WithOptionalDependent()` and I failed to understand the functionality. I did see that, in the DB, the FK were wrong and so I ditched this approach as it seemed not to work for me. Glad that it wasn't EF failing but me.

Comment: I would recommend you reading and using as reference the [Associations in EF Code First](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-1-introduction-and-basic-concepts) blog series.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework doesn't like relationships where there is no clear principal. In this case as either entity can exist without the other, neither is dependent on the other.

I would suggest redesigning your model so that you have an abstract class `Building` which `House` and `Garage` both derive from. You can then link your `Person` to a `Building`, and in the concrete types 'House' and `Garage` have a link to a `Building` for the association.

Example:

```
public abstract class Building
{
    public Person Person { Get; Set; }

    public Building Building { Get; Set; }
}

public class House : Building
{
    // Other House properties
}

public class Garage : Building
{
    // Other Garage properties
}
```

Then in the business logic you can enforce that the associated building cannot be of the same type with something like `this.GetType() != Building.GetType()`

Comment: Excellent idea, I will try to implement it right now.

Comment: Unfortunately defining `public Building ConnectedBuilding { get; set; }` also causes `Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.`, how would I define the ordering when self-referencing?

Comment: I've also tried defining an optional `Garage` in `House` and vice versa, caused `Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'DatabaseTest.Garage' and 'DatabaseTest.House'.`
As soon as I define any `Building`-derived class in any of the `Building`-based classes, it causes the same issues like before, either having trouble figuring out the order or not being able to find the principal end at all. It weirds me out that EF has such trouble with this kind of relation.